# ID Assignment not working outside scope of click function - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I need to assign an ID to a variable from inside a click function but carry that assignment as well from outside the scope of the function, although i get an 'undefined' if i test for it outside of the click function.(Im not asking about the answer below,my fault)

```
// var for button
var $firstMobButton;

 $(".preLoaderTest").click(function(){

     var checkDiv = $(this);

     if(checkDiv.attr("id") == "showPreLoader"){
          $firstMobButton = $("#showPreLoader");

         alert($firstMobButton); // object

     }else if(checkDiv.attr("id") == "showPreLoaderDebt"){
         $firstMobButton = $("#showPreLoaderDebt");

         alert($firstMobButton); // object
     }
 });
   // this function doesnt assign the variable to the id OUTSIDE the If statement ...thats what i meant, Sorry i didnt explain well, i didnt mean what it is on instant load, i mean what is it after this function gets carried out)
```

solved:

```
   $(".preLoaderTest").click(function(){
    var checkDiv = $(this);
    if(checkDiv.attr("id") == "showPreLoader"){ // check for an id for this partial view
```

the best way was not to try and assign an ID but to give the button a class then test later if the button had an ID, thanks to Quentin for putting me on the right track...

if you're interested, the full solution:

```
    // grab dataSource for unselected value
    var $yourAge = yourAge.view(); // change this dataSource value
    // function call on click if onSelect empty html
    $(".preLoaderTest").click(function(){
        var checkDiv = $(this);
        if(checkDiv.attr("id") == "showPreLoader"){ // check for an id for this partial view
        if($("#displayNextSelection").html() === "") {
            $("#displayNextSelection").html('<p class="selectFeedBack">You age: ' + '<b>' + $yourAge[0].text + '</b>' + '</p>');
            $disDeskSel2.html('<p><span class="label label-primary label-ls">Based on your selection </span> You age: ' + $yourAge[0].text + '</p>')
                .hide();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You get undefined because until the button is clicked it is what it's value is. That's normal. After `$()` will return a jQuery instance containing the element you can then use `attr()` to set the id on it.

Comment: please re read the question, i made a mistake

Answer (score 3):

> Before click event it will always show **undefined** in your case.

This is because your `alert($firstMobButton);` executing before click method.

---

You can get value of `$firstMobButton` after click is done. Like:

```
$(".preLoaderTest").click(function(){

     var checkDiv = $(this);

     if(checkDiv.attr("id") == "showPreLoader"){
          $firstMobButton = $("#showPreLoader");

         alert($firstMobButton); // object

     }else if(checkDiv.attr("id") == "showPreLoaderDebt"){
         $firstMobButton = $("#showPreLoaderDebt");

         alert($firstMobButton); // object
     }
     checkValue();//calling after click is done

 });

function checkValue() {
    alert($firstMobButton); 
}
```

---

Another solution is you can manually `trigger` click event before alert:

```
$(".preLoaderTest").click(function(){

     var checkDiv = $(this);

     if(checkDiv.attr("id") == "showPreLoader"){
          $firstMobButton = $("#showPreLoader");

         alert($firstMobButton); // object

     }else if(checkDiv.attr("id") == "showPreLoaderDebt"){
         $firstMobButton = $("#showPreLoaderDebt");

         alert($firstMobButton); // object
     }

 });

$(".preLoaderTest").trigger('click')// manually triggering click event
alert($firstMobButton);
```

Comment: i dont want to know that, i want to know how to add an event listener to a variable using an if statement –

Comment: You can't add event listener to variable. You can only add event listener to DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

You assign a value to `$firstMobButton` **when preLoaderTest is clicked**.

You try to alert it **immediately** (which is going to be before then, since you've only just registered the event handler).

JavaScript can't violate the rules of linear time!

Comment: if(checkDiv.attr("id") == "showPreLoader"){
             var $firstMobButton = $("#showPreLoader");
         }else if(checkDiv.attr("id") == "showPreLoaderDebt"){
            var $firstMobButton = $("#showPreLoaderDebt");
         }

Comment: yea its this function above , it doesnt assign the ID to the variable after all, any ideas on a similiar way of doing this?

Comment: You just need to make sure that things happen in the order you want. You can't alert the value before you've selected it.

Comment: i dont want to know that, i want to know how to add an event listener to a variable using an if statement

Comment: You call `.on()` on the jQuery object instead of assigning it to a variable.

Comment: i just didnt want to change a load of code but ill have too, thanks!

Comment: Solved it, see my original question, thanks Quentin you put me on the right track

Answer (score 0):

Since your variable is not assigned until your button is clicked it will be `undefined` until then. You will be able to use the variable once the click is ran and the variable is assigned as the variable is defined in the global scope.

Your code is executed as follows:

```
 var $firstMobButton; // variable $firstMobButton is defined with undefined value
 $(".preLoaderTest").click(function(){
     // a click handler is attached to an element
 });
 $(".test").click(function () {
     alert($firstMobButton); // click this one after the preLoaderTest
 });
 alert($firstMobButton); // Your variable is still not assigned to, so undefined
```

Comment: i dont want to know that, i want to know how to add an event listener to a variable using an if statement –